# RegEx to extract ids from links

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to extract ids from links below:

```
shipments/8891cbf6-f3d4-4369-9ae0-fdb794a8b61d/documents/routingLabel
https://example1.com/service/document-generation-service/retrieve/J75pYky-5kAreVLVrmR2sYf-svE0abvqW8QDdQg44CFMUj6YtsxveeAQY8iJX_cgeb1OV4vFfZBohGSngpIb3Q/addressLabel
http://example2.com/service/document-generation-service/retrieve/J75pYky-5kAreVLVrmR2sYf-svE0abvqW8QDdQg44CFMUj6YtsxveeAQY8iJX_cgeb1OV4vFfZBohGSngpIb3Q/addressLabel
```

These are ids from links above:

```
8891cbf6-f3d4-4369-9ae0-fdb794a8b61d
J75pYky-5kAreVLVrmR2sYf-svE0abvqW8QDdQg44CFMUj6YtsxveeAQY8iJX_cgeb1OV4vFfZBohGSngpIb3Q
J75pYky-5kAreVLVrmR2sYf-svE0abvqW8QDdQg44CFMUj6YtsxveeAQY8iJX_cgeb1OV4vFfZBohGSngpIb3Q
```

I wrote 2 regex that extracts these ids, but do not know how to combine them to one.

This is for the first type `shipments\/(.*?)\/`.

This is for the second and third type of links: 
`document-generation-service\/retrieve\/(.*?)\/`

Can I combine them to one regex that will work for all type of my links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can combine them by using an `|` (or):

`(shipments|document-generation-service\/retrieve)\/(.*?)\/`

Your token id will now be in captured group #2

See result for all links below:

```js
const urls = [
    "shipments/8891cbf6-f3d4-4369-9ae0-fdb794a8b61d/documents/routingLabel",
    "https://example1.com/service/document-generation-service/retrieve/J75pYky-5kAreVLVrmR2sYf-svE0abvqW8QDdQg44CFMUj6YtsxveeAQY8iJX_cgeb1OV4vFfZBohGSngpIb3Q/addressLabel",
    "http://example2.com/service/document-generation-service/retrieve/J75pYky-5kAreVLVrmR2sYf-svE0abvqW8QDdQg44CFMUj6YtsxveeAQY8iJX_cgeb1OV4vFfZBohGSngpIb3Q/addressLabel"
],
ids = urls.map(url => url.match(/(shipments|document-generation-service\/retrieve)\/(.*?)\//)[2]);

console.log(ids); // List of id's retrieved from the above URLS
```

Comment: @rel1x  no worries, glad to help :)